# How to pass 'this' and other parameters in onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I pass the DOM element and a string in an HTML onclick attribute:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="load_page(this,'predictions')">
```

The above code calls the following function:

```
function load_page (_this,page) {
    console.log(_this); // 'predictions'
    console.log(page); // undefined
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         //data: data,
         url: "/controller/"+page,
         success: function(response) {
             $("#page_content").html(response);
        },
        error: function(response, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus); 
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        }  
    });
}
```

As you can see from the code comments, the parameters get muddled up and one of them shows up undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing shown would explain those results. Can not reproduce here https://jsfiddle.net/pqw93dxp/1

Comment: I tested this in my browser and didn't have this result. If you provide more code, it might give a better indication of the error.

Comment: Did you accidentally include a comma before `_this` in your `load_page` function definition or where you call `page_load`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't properly close the "a" (it requires "/a"), though I think you are looking for more than that as an answer, so here's mine.

To pass more than 'this' to a function, the 'best' way is to use 'data';

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-something='predictions' onclick="load_page(this)">link</a>
```

To retrieve the data:

```
function load_page (e) {
    console.log(e); 
    var something1 = e.dataset.something;
    console.log(something1);
 }
```

using 'data', you can add all the variables/info you like.

I know, it is quite odd looking to use 'data' in the element and 'dataset' in the function, but that is one of the weird things about javascript.  As you learn, you can take on jQuery, which makes it simpler to remember the command.

More on the javascript way of this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: While this is an alternate way to accomplish the same thing, his original method should work just as well.